# Why can't OP accept more than one answer?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I recently asked the question: [Buying life insurance at the age of 25](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/23258/buying-life-insurance-at-the-age-of-25) and got a good amount of replies. I wanted to accept more than one answer as the OP.

Why is it that I couldn't accept more answers even if they sound appropriate? I think I am not able to give credit for the other answers if just one answer is acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that we're about

> practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.

And the system is engineered to getting you useful answers to those questions, and making them easily available to the internet.

If an answer is valuable, give it an upvote.  You can do that for as many answers as you like.  Then pick the one that was most valuable to you, the one you actually *used* and mark that as accepted.  This will help future visitors see what worked for you, but they'll still be able to see the other up-voted answers.

<sub>A little bit of this is legacy, the engine was designed to do Q&A on technical subjects where the users presumably implemented only one of the answers.</sub>

Comment: [The goal isn't to have multiple answers each containing a piece of the puzzle. It's to have a single, correct, comprehensive answer.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2786/accept-multiple-answers-or-split-bounty-among-several-users?lq=1)  That's not legacy to my eye; that's by design.

Comment: @GeorgeMarian I don't disagree, but in Money it's harder to say "I used this particular answer".

Comment: I really can't see how it's any different because "Money is harder."  In fact, that's all the more reason.  Please, let's not muddy things any further.  We're already dealing with complex topics.  So, pick the single best answer, if one exists.  If not, no big deal.  Let the internet do its job.  Ultimately, how  do "you" know what the answer is if you're asking the internet?

Answer (score 7):

That is how the system is designed.  You're only supposed to be able to accept one answer.  There is less confusion that way.

In the long run, the up-votes on the answers usually add up to more points than an accepted answer.